# Pace: Track $http requests in angularjs?

Tags: pace

Question from github:

https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/issues/154

I'm trying to get pace to work with my angularjs app. Everything works fine with page loads but when I make a $http call pace doesn't show the progress. Any ideas?

I tried using this library but it isn't as configurable as I would like, it does however with with $http.
https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar

- Tom

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try **loading the following options before including pace.js** in your index.html

```
window.paceOptions = {
    document: true, // disabled
    eventLag: true,
    restartOnPushState: true,
    restartOnRequestAfter: true,
    ajax: {
        trackMethods: [ 'POST','GET']
    }
};
```

Comment: For someone who overlooked the important bit like me,  `load the options before including pace.js`

Comment: Didnt work at all